# How to install pyaudio on Ubuntu 18.04 using Anaconda?

Tags: anaconda, ubuntu-18.04, pyaudio

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.  I have an Anaconda environment set up to use Python3.  I have unsuccessfully tried to install pyaudio so that I can record from microphone in my environment.

I tried:

```
conda install -c anaconda pyaudio
```

I can import pyaudio and create an instance, but it does not find any devices, despite microphone, hdmi output and external speakers being available from PulseAudio.

```
import pyaudio


p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
p.get_device_count()

0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved thanks to advice from David Nicholson.

I re-installed pyaudio from the source-forge channel instead of Anaconda channel, and that version finds devices.